# Декомпиляция приложения

Tags: android, компиляция, reverse-engineering, декомпиляция, smali

У меня есть готовое приложение, мне нужно его декомпилировать внести изменения и компилировать, скачал приложение для декомпиляции легкое в использовании `ANDROID MULTITOOL`, все бы было хорошо, если бы не одно но java классы стали `SMALI`, и очень тяжелы для редактирования, подскажите каким приложением можно было бы нормально декомпилирвать чтоб оставались java классы? Или какая то прога для редактирования `SMALI` в `JAVA`

Comment: Посмотрите dex2jar. Но java классы вы сможете использовать только для чтения, редактировать код придется в smali

Comment: @Соколов при использовании dex2jar файлы не компилируется обратно я так понял ?единственный вариант для редактирования и компиляции обратно это все надо делать через SMALI я правильно все понял?

Comment: Чисто теоретически это возможно, но декомпилятор не всегда справляется с кодом smaili, из-за этого код java скорей всего просто не скомпилируется или будет работать не так как нужно. Но для анализа сгодится. Рекомендую [эту статейку](https://sohabr.net/habr/post/301832/)

Answer (score 0):

Описание типа SMALI: http://open-file.ru/types/smali

Рекомендую прочитать эту статью: https://habrahabr.ru/post/141522/

Также, загляните сюда: https://www.quora.com/What-is-smali-in-Android

И просьба: перед тем, как писать сюда, не забудьте погуглить.

Также, на всякий случай напомню, что декомпИляция чужих приложений, внесение в них изменений и т.д. влечёт за собой уголовную ответственность (нарушение авторских и смежных прав)!

Comment: Можно пруф про уголовную ответственность? И причем тут авторские права вообще?

Comment: ну во первых описания SMALI я и так знал,просьба была в другом,во вторых статью которую вы кинули я читал и там не было того что мне нужно,я думал мне помогут люди опытные в данном деле,увы попались вы,в третьих я погуглил больше чем вы ,а скидывать первые ссылки сюда это глупо ,а про последнее я вообще промолчу )))

Comment: Пожалуйста, указывайте в ответе самое главное, а ссылки можете приводить в качестве источника. Если страницы, на которые ведут ссылки, будут изменены, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.